# Why does "tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)" work in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

The standard usage should be

`tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)`, isn't it?

I saw the `tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)` in official documentation. The constructor function prototype of  `tf.Variable` is

`__init__(self, initial_value=None, trainable=True, collections=None, validate_shape=True, caching_device=None, name=None, variable_def=None, dtype=None, expected_shape=None, import_scope=None)`.

If we pass the parameter `tf.float32` instead of `dtype=tf.float32` (key parameter), how does it know the `tf.float32` is employed for `dtype`. Does python interpreter check the parameter type?

Comment: The answer why it works is given by @kaufmanu - just to make it clear: This is a bug in the TF documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started and only works by accident, so feel free to open a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `tf.Variable`:

> dtype: If set, initial_value will be converted to the given type.
>           If `None`, either the datatype will be kept (if `initial_value` is
>           a Tensor), or `convert_to_tensor` will decide.

And the documentation from `convert_to_tensor(value, dtype=None, ...)`:

> dtype: Optional element type for the returned tensor. If missing, the
>         type is inferred from the type of `value`.

Also, there is an example given in the documentation to `convert_to_tensor`:

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(arg):
    arg = tf.convert_to_tensor(arg, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(arg, arg) + arg

# The following calls are equivalent.
value_1 = my_func(tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]))
value_2 = my_func([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
value_3 = my_func(np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], dtype=np.float32))
```

So, coming back to your question - Tensorflow does not know that you intended to use `tf.float32`, it just happened to be the datatype that was chosen by default by the `convert_to_tensor` function. Hence, it was mere coincidence that the returned Tensor had the datatype that you expected. If e.g. you call `tf.Variable([.3], tf.float64)` the resulting Tensor has the same `dtype` as when calling `tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)`.

In fact, I believe that both calls `tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)` and `tf.Variable([.3], tf.float64)` are equivalent, as the second argument to `tf.Variable` is a boolean and thus `tf.floatX` is being converted to a boolean which always returns `True`.