# Why is the type of tf.Variable([8.0], tf.float64) float 32 rather than float 64 in TensorFlow?

Tags: types, casting, tensorflow

**(Updated question)**
I think the original question is confusing, and I found a simpler way to ask this question.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable([2], tf.float32)
print x.dtype
```

If we try the above code segment, then the output is as follows:

```
<dtype: 'int32_ref'>
```

Since I explicitly specified the type of `x` as tf.float32, I had thought that the type should be float32. However, it seems like the type is int32.

Could somebody answer this question?

---

**(original question)**

I tried the following code to replace one element of a 2-D tensorflow array.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ref = tf.Variable(np.arange(0, 12).reshape((4, 3)).astype(np.float64))
indices = tf.constant([[2, 2]])
updates = tf.Variable([8.0], tf.float64)
ref = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, indices, updates)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run(init)
  print sess.run(ref)
```

Strangely, I encountered the following type error:

**TypeError: Input 'updates' of 'ScatterNdUpdate' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'ref'.**

After changing `tf.Variable([8.0], tf.float64)` to the following line, it worked.

```
updates = tf.Variable(np.array([8.0]).astype(np.float64), tf.float64)
```

So, it seems like the type of `tf.Variable([8.0], tf.float64)` is not tf.float64, even though I explicitly specified the type as tf.float64. Could anyone tell me the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is really simple: your code create a `tf.Variable` which is trainable (your `tf.float64` is interpreted as a `True` for the `trainable` argument. If you just add `dtype`, it will work:

```
    updates = tf.Variable([8.0], dtype=tf.float64)
```

Actually, there was a similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899188/4282745).

Answer (score 0):

*Update:*

Use dtype when using tf.Variable()

*Original Question:*

making *ref* type to float32 is working for me.

Do

```
ref = tf.Variable(np.arange(0, 12).reshape((4, 3)).astype(np.float32))
```

or

```
ref = tf.Variable(np.arange(0, 12).reshape((4, 3)),dtype=tf.float32)
```

I guess, ScatterNdUpdate operation works only for float32 not float64.